# SCITE4Autohotkey: Hotkey to Reload script again after pressing F5?

Tags: autohotkey

In SCITE4auto hotkey I know you can press F5 to run a script. But after this is been done you can NOT press F5 again to reload the script. Is there a hotkey to be able to reload the script at any time? I don't know what version it was but I remember there was a version where I could press ctrl shift R at any time and it would reload the script for me.

But in the newest version that keyboard shortcut does something else. Does anyone know of a hotkey to reload the script at any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use: Ctrl+Win+Alt+e = edit and Ctrl+Win+Alt+r = save and reload.

```
^!#e::Edit   ; Edit the script by Alt+Ctrl+Win+e, set SCITE4 as default editor first

$^!#r::
Send, ^s
Sleep, 500
Reload ; Reload the script
Return
```